# Redirect with express in serverless/lambda container not working

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda, serverless

I have setup an express application with various routes like:

- /api/route1
- /api/route2
- /api/newroute
- …

I need to redirect a request for route */api/route2* to */api/newroute*. Thus I use *res.redirect();* to achieve this. It works fine on my local development environment, where the application is hosted on http://localhost/api. A request for http://localhost/api/route2 gets successfully redirected to http://localhost/api/newroute.

We have now deployed the express application in a serverless/lambda container using *aws-serverless-express*. The application is hosted by AWS on https://xxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/production/api.

In case of a request for:

https://xxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/production/api/route2

it gets redirected to:

https://xxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/api/newroute.

The redirect fails as the correct endpoint should be now **/production**/api/newroute.

I would like to avoid to hardcode the infix “/production” in res.redirect(); as the it will vary due to environment.

Thus I have checked whether

- req.originalUrl
- req.baseUrl
- req.path

will provide the infix “/production”, however this is not the case.

Also *req.get('Host')* does not provide “/production” as it returns https://xxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com.

Are there any other options how I could get the full URL where the application is hosted? Or are there any better ideas?

Comment: Why not make the `stage` a variable? Directly pull it from your environment file.

Comment: This would add more complexity. I would prefere omit the stage variable. Is there any way to deploy a serverless application without stage infix?

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this same issue. Here's my solution:

```
const baseUrl = req.url
      .replace(
        event.pathParameters.proxy, // => returns api/your/path
        event.requestContext.path // => returns /production//api/your/path
      )
      .split('//') // fix the double-slashes (//)
      .join('/');
```